# Is there any etymological link between template and contemplate

Tags: etymology

Wikitionary doesn't seem to think there is (unless I am misreading)

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/template

> Alteration of templet, probably from French templet, diminutive of temple (“a weaver's stretcher”), variant of tempe, from Latin tempora (“temple”). Alteration of second syllable due to analogy with plate. Cognate with Faroese tamba (“to stretch out, relax”), Icelandic þamb (“a stretched, bloated, or extended belly”).

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contemplate

> Attested since the 1590s; borrowed from Latin contemplātus, from contemplari (“observe, survey”).

Comment: Not since assimilation into the lexis. Before that, Latin Language.SE is the place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncertain.

There are two Latin words *templum*, one meaning an open space and hence an open space for religious devotion and thence a temple, and the other meaning a small timber, a plank.

Short's Latin Dictionary ([online at Tufts' Perseus](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=templum)) doesn't provide an etymology for the latter, and I can't find one elsewhere. So there's no proof they're connected although it's possible. *Templum* in the sense of a place cut out and a place of worship probably comes from the PIE root **tem-* "to cut" although it might come from **ten-* "to stretch" ([Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/temple)). You could guess that the other Latin word comes from one of those roots, but I wouldn't guess which one.

Thence, *template* derives from the Latin word *templum* for plank, later referring to other similar strips of wood; French and English *templet* originally meant a piece of wood under a beam or a weaver's stretcher (a piece of wood used to ensure a regular spacing between threads, still commonly called a *temple* in English), and was extended to mean a piece of wood used as a pattern for cutting ([Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/template)). *Contemplate* comes from the Latin word *templum* for temple ([Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/contemplate)).